# How to change an array max in Python

Tags: python

I want to change the max value of a list as below:

```
a = [2, 2, 4, 5]

max(a) = 10

print(a)
```

but consistently get: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Does anybody know how to change the max value?

Thank everyone for the help! I want to replace the maximum of an array with another number, which will be my new maximum.

Comment: How do you expect the list to look after this operation?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. As the error message said, `max` is a function and not something to be substituted. Do you want to change the max value in a given list to another number?

Comment: do you want to append 10 in list as a max value ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change all max values of the array, for example [1, 2, 5, 5] to [1, 2, new_max, new_max], then you can do the following:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 5, 5])
a[a == a.max()] = new_max
```

Answer (score 4):

Since max returns the largest element, you can do something like this:

`a[a.index(max(a))] = 10`

This will change the largest (max) value in your list to be 10.

Comment: This will cause error when there are multi max value. ex: a = [2, 4, 5, 5] , a[a.index(max(a))] = 10, a equals [2, 4, 10, 5]

Comment: I answered only based on what OP was asking. Also, that won't be an error. Rather, `index` returns the lowest index only.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a function that tells you the index of the maximum element (what instead C++ `std::max_element` or numpy `argmax` are doing), so you need to:

1. find the max with `mx = max(a)`
2. find the index where the max is `ix = a.index(mx)`
3. change the element `a[ix] = 10`

you can combine the three steps in a single line with

```
a[a.index(max(a))] = 10
```

Note that this won't ensure that after the operation `max(a)` changed... for example:

```
a = [10, 30, 20, 30]
a[a.index(max(a))] = 15
# now a is [10, 15, 20, 30] and max is still 30
```

If you want to change all max elements to a new value you need either to loop explicitly or to use a comprehension

```
mx = max(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == mx:
        a[i] = new_max
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose `a = [1,2,3,4]` and you want to change max to 100

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == max(a):
        a[i] = 100
```